# C# - Multiple queries DataSet

Tags: c#, dataset, foreach

I want to create a DataSet with multiple queries. Then add the rows that the dataset returns to a listbox. 
This is what I have so far. My SqlCommand contains multiple queries, I want to add each value from the query to the dataset and then create a `foreach` statement to get all the rows from the dataset into a `listbox`

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select ProductID AS ProductID from Products; Select CategoryName AS CategoryName from Categories; Select count(*) AS Total from Products", con);

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

        DataSet set = new DataSet();           

        sda.Fill(set);
```

Enyone has eny idéa how I could do that?
Many thnx in advance.

Comment: Do the queries have the same result format (column names and types)?

Comment: No each has its own name and type. I should add a coulumn the to the query.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you're making a list box of 3 very different datas, some product IDs, some category names and a count of products. Its a little confusing to me. However.

If for example you had wanted to have products and categories in the same listbox, you could have done

```
    select productname as dataname from products 
union 
select categoryname as dataname from categories
```

Comment: Sorry about the confussion, I want to list all the rows in the SAME listbox and not different listboxes.

Comment: Thats what the above does, it would take all the product names, and category names and return them in 1 list. I realised it was not different list boxes which is why some numeric PIDs and a count of products would seem out of place all going to the same listbox.

Comment: @BugFinder: When I add the union statement to my code just like yours, it doesent work for men, I only get the ProductName in my listbox

Comment: You need all 3 data types to be the same. Which a count(*) returns an integer where as category name of course is a string.. so, Iam still puzzled why you would want a listbox of those items combined..

Comment: @BugFinder: Iam going to create a HTML report based on these items.

Comment: OK, so if your data was returned { 101,233,6728,Shoes, Drills, Cakes, 238 } How are you going to use it? Surely you want to get the product IDs, do that part of the report, get the categories, do that part, and then display number of products .. or are you trying to do something more than is shown in your original query, such as, you want to know an individual product ID, which categories its in, and then how many other products are in those individual categories.

Comment: @BugFinder: I want to show all the information in the same report. In the report I have diffrent section for each query. Section one is where I show the information about the products, section two is where I show information about the categories and section three is where I show how many products I have in my product table.

Comment: Then stick with 3 separate queries. You will be making your life very difficult if you dont. Run each in turn for the 3 sections you wanted.

Comment: @BugFinder: The this is my ReportSource takes one dataset. If stick with 3 seperate queries I wont have all the information in the same report. I could create diffrent reports for each query but I want all the information in the same report.

Comment: OK, so I go back to the question. If you had { 101,233,6728,Shoes, Drills, Cakes, 238 } as your data, your report isnt going to know where things stopped and where new things started. I Im going to back out of this, as clearly I wont be able to offer a solution